# Instagram API - retrieve other users photos

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, instagram

Using the Instagram API, I'm able to return my own recent photos:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[my-user-id]/media/recent?client_id=[my-client-id]
```

However, I'm unable to retrieve that of other users using `[other-user-id]`, even though I'm able to do so in the [API console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/).  Here's the JavaScript code I'm using

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[my-user-id]/media/recent?client_id=[client-id]', 
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function(data){
        console.log('got data ', data)
    }
})
```

Note, using post to avoid issues with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: I don't have any problem retreiving data from another user using the above code? Are you sure that the user you trying to get media for has a public profile?

Comment: Interesting -- i didn't know people had non-public profiles.  I'm able to do this with some other users (20053826, brunomars).  Any idea how to get access to a person that I follow?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I think the user must allow your client to view the profile.

Comment: Do you know of a way using the API to have a user input info to get their own information (ie, if I had an input for username and password?) Might get tricky in terms of privacy....

Comment: If you look here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints it seems like `Private media is returned as long as the authenticated user has permission to view that media`

Comment: Hmmm... I do have permission to view the media.  Is my client_id not the authenticated user?

Comment: If you're talking about some way for a user to login and allow your client some privileges, this would be possible: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use oAuth instead of Client Id.

Here is an example.

Step 1: Redirect user to instagram login.

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token">Instagram Login</a>
```

On return, strip out the access token like this:

```
function AccessToken(value) {
    this.value = value;
}

function getInstagramAccessToken() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '')
    if(hash.indexOf("access_token") >= 0 ){
        instagramToken = new AccessToken(hash)
    }else{
        instagramToken = null;
    }
}
```

Ste 2: Once authenticated, make the call like this:

```
var photoList_Instagram = []
function getInstagramPhotoList(nextPageUrl) {

    var requestUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent' + "?"
    + instagramToken.value

    if(nextPageUrl){
        requestUrl = nextPageUrl;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        url : requestUrl,
        success : function(response) {
            response.data.forEach(function(photo){
                photoList_Instagram.push(photo);
            })
            if (response.pagination.next_url) {

                getInstagramPhotoList(response.pagination.next_url)

            } else {
                //your code here
                foo(photoList_Instagram);
            }
        }
    });
```